# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::detach does not exist. (how can I solve?)

Tags: many-to-many, laravel-7, detach

I need to delete and detach all relationship between BrandName table and stellar_category table.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $brand_name = BrandName::find($id);
    $brand_name->stellar_category->detach();

    $brand_name->delete();
    return back()->withMessage('Your Brand is Deleted');`enter code here`

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change it to

```
$brand_name->stellar_category()->detach();
```